# Fitting matplotlib histogram gives bad result (and only 2 parameters)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a few questions about fitting a histogram in python with matplotlib.

1. My histogram is a spectrum, so I can't just fit the entire histogram, I have to select a region where I want to do the fit. My code below creates a special region for fitting, but I wonder if there's a less clumsy way to do this
2. For some reason, "scipy.stats.norm.fit" only returns mu and sigma, whereas a Gaussian fit obviously has 3 parameters: mean, sigma and the amplitude. So, how do I get the amplitude of the fit?
3. Clearly, from the attached image, one can see that the fit (green line) is not very good. The mean and sigma are fine but the amplitude is not high enough. The data looks Gaussian enough for a much better fit, so how can I improve this?

```
# Start or E fitting <<<<<<<<<
plt.figure(1)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(array_E, bins=1400, range=(0.0,1.400), label="Energy", color="blue")

# We know that the mean should be 0.511, so we select the region around the peak...
mass_emin = 0.511
delta = 0.008 # 0.010
peak_E = []
for E in array_E:
    if ( (E > mass_emin - delta) and (E < mass_emin + delta) ):
        peak_E.append(E)
plt.hist(peak_E, bins=1400, range=(0.0,1.400), label="Energy peak", color="red")

mu, sigma = scipy.stats.norm.fit(peak_E)
print("fit results: ", mu, sigma)
best_fit_line = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)
plt.plot(bins, best_fit_line, color="green")

plt.show(block=False)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.stats.norm.pdf` is a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), and as such its area totals to `1`. To draw it at the same size as the red bars, you can calculate the area of these bars (the sum of their heights times their width). And then multiply the pdf with that area:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

# first create some toy data, somewhat similar to the example plot
array_E = np.random.randn(100, 1000).cumsum(axis=1).ravel() * 0.0005 + 0.511
plt.figure(1)
_, bins, _ = plt.hist(array_E, bins=1400, range=(0.0, 1.400), label="Energy", color="blue")

mass_emin = 0.511
delta = 0.008
peak_E = array_E[np.abs(array_E - mass_emin) < delta]
n, _, _ = plt.hist(peak_E, bins=1400, range=(0.0, 1.400), label="Energy peak", color="red")
bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]
area = np.sum(n) * bin_width

mu, sigma = scipy.stats.norm.fit(peak_E)
print("fit results: ", mu, sigma)
best_fit_line = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma) * area
plt.plot(bins, best_fit_line, color="green")
plt.xlim(mass_emin - 3 * delta, mass_emin + 3 * delta)  # zoom into the region on the x-axis
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: The following code calculates a measure of the error:

```py
bin_mids = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
squared_error = ((scipy.stats.norm.pdf(bin_mids, mu, sigma) * area - n) ** 2).sum()
print("squared_error div degrees_of_freedom: ", squared_error / (n.size - 3))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this but I am a bit surprised how complicated apparantly this fitting business in Python is. I am used to the cern program ROOT (based on C++) and with that software it's possible to 1) select a region of a histogram to be fitted and 2) directly fit a Gaussian on top of the data without having to multiply anything. Isn't there some library available in python which does that? I tried Numpy but couldn't find what I looked for.

Comment: Well, each software has its specific functions. In this case the area is quite straightforward to calculate. As the area depends on the bin width, a fit can only be calculated given a histogram and not as a standalone numpy function with only the samples as input. You can see the changes on the y-axis after changing the `bins=` parameter.

Comment: Okay, I guess I will have to get used to this when I want to use python. Is there also a way to get the Chi-square from the fit? Because a fit is not much use without knowing the quality of it.